# I want to merge my PEFT adapter model with the base model and make a fully new model

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, peft

As the title said, I want to merge my PEFT LoRA adapter model ([ArcturusAI/Crystalline-1.1B-v23.12-tagger](https://huggingface.co/ArcturusAI/Crystalline-1.1B-v23.12-tagger)) that I trained before with the base model ([TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v0.6](https://huggingface.co/TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v0.6)) and make a fully new model.

And I got this code from ChatGPT:

```py
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoConfig

# Load the pretrained model and LoRA adapter
pretrained_model_name = "TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v0.6"

pretrained_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name)
lora_adapter = AutoModel.from_pretrained("ArcturusAI/Crystalline-1.1B-v23.12-tagger")

# Assuming the models have the same architecture (encoder, decoder, etc.)
# Get the weights of each model
pretrained_weights = pretrained_model.state_dict()
lora_adapter_weights = lora_adapter.state_dict()

# Combine the weights (adjust the weights based on your preference)
combined_weights = {}
for key in pretrained_weights:
    combined_weights[key] = 0.8 * pretrained_weights[key] + 0.2 * lora_adapter_weights[key]

# Load the combined weights into the pretrained model
pretrained_model.load_state_dict(combined_weights)

# Save the integrated model
pretrained_model.save_pretrained("ArcturusAI/Crystalline-1.1B-v23.12-tagger-fullmodel")
```

And I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-d2120d727884> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 pretrained_model_name = "TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v0.6"
      5 pretrained_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name)
----> 6 lora_adapter = AutoModel.from_pretrained("ArcturusAI/Crystalline-1.1B-v23.12-tagger")
      7 
      8 # Assuming the models have the same architecture (encoder, decoder, etc.)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir, ignore_mismatched_sizes, force_download, local_files_only, token, revision, use_safetensors, *model_args, **kwargs)
   3096                             )
   3097                         else:
-> 3098                             raise EnvironmentError(
   3099                                 f"{pretrained_model_name_or_path} does not appear to have a file named"
   3100                                 f" {_add_variant(WEIGHTS_NAME, variant)}, {TF2_WEIGHTS_NAME}, {TF_WEIGHTS_NAME} or"

OSError: ArcturusAI/Crystalline-1.1B-v23.12-tagger does not appear to have a file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt or flax_model.msgpack.
```

I have no idea what I did wrong there, I would appreciate it if anyone could teach me how to fix it, or am I going in a completely wrong direction? Thank you.

I tried using `transformers` and `pytorch`, I expect them to merge both models and create a new model out of it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter can't be loaded with AutoModel from `transformers` and also the suggestion from ChatGPT of merging won't work. Luckily you don't need to rely on AI for that. The peft library has everything ready for you with [merge_and_unload](https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/v0.6.2/en/package_reference/tuners#peft.LoraModel.merge_and_unload):

```py
from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM

# Local path, check post scriptum for explanation
model_id = "./ArcturusAI/Crystalline-1.1B-v23.12-tagger"
peft_model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
print(type(peft_model))

merged_model = peft_model.merge_and_unload()
# The adapters are merged now and it is transformers class again
print(type(merged_model))
```

Output:

```
<class 'peft.peft_model.PeftModelForCausalLM'>
<class 'transformers.models.llama.modeling_llama.LlamaForCausalLM'>
```

You can now save `merged_model` with [save_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.35.2/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.save_pretrained) or do with it whatever you want.

Please note that this is only the model and not the tokenizer. You still need to load the tokenizer from the `TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v0.6` repo and save it with [save_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.35.2/en/internal/tokenization_utils#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.save_pretrained) locally to have everything in one place:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
t = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v0.6")
```

P.S.: I noticed that you have trained the model with a different version of `peft`. Hence I downloaded it locally and removed the following keys from the adapter_config.json:

- loftq_config,
- megatron_config,
- megatron_core

to be able to load it with `peft==0.6.2`.