# convert a PeftModel back to the original model but with updated weights

Tags: huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper, peft

I finetuned an `opeai-whisper` model using `LoRa` with `huggingface`. I want to "unwrap" this model so that I end up with the original `WhisperForConditionalGeneration` or `WhisperModel` model. I also want the `LoRa` layer weights to be added to the original weights, preserving the original model architecture. I searched around but can't seem to find any API that can do this conversion.

> PeftModel

[image: model]

> WhisperForConditionalGeneration model

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to merge my PEFT adapter model with the base model and make a fully new model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77596271/i-want-to-merge-my-peft-adapter-model-with-the-base-model-and-make-a-fully-new-m)